# Scripting language to find the .a file name from the concatenated nm output for a list of .a files

Tags: python, ruby, perl, bash, scripting

I have a file with the nm output for all the .a files in an application. Now, how do I find out the .a which contains a specified function.

I am good with Bash scripting and am fairly competent in Perl and can do some Python and Ruby.

Any suggestions on the scripting language I can use for doing this?

Question update:
I have a file which I created with the following command:

```
$ find . -name '*'.a > afile_list.log
$ while read line; do echo "$line"; nm $line; done < ./afile_list.log > a_list.log
```

Now I have a function fun1() in the codebase. How do I find out which of the .a's has this function in it?

Comment: Your question is bit unclear. run a 'strace' on binary and see if it's output is helpful to you.

Comment: If you want to search files in a directory for a particular string, use [grep](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nm` command has an option to print that information on its output, which then makes the tracking trivial.  The option `nm -A` includes the library name and member object file name on Linux, Mac OS X and Solaris (HP-UX and AIX not checked), in conformity with [POSIX `nm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nm.html), which explains the uniformity.  There are other options that do similar tasks on some of the platforms; `nm -R` on Solaris, for example.

Answer (score 0):

bash can do this. Use a `while read` loop to read the file line by line squirreling away the archive name each time one is encountered, and output the last archive name stored when you find the function of interest.

Comment: I have implemented this using bash... however, I find that it is not the most optimal way to do things. :(